# Print a mixture of text from a file and save output in another text file

Tags: python

I have this little python script running fine:

```
with open('xxxxxxx.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'Neuro' in line:
            print line
```

But I'd like to print all lines with 'neuro' or 'brain' or 'whatever' etc. and then save the output to a text file - any tips much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search specific lines in a file and write them to another file, using function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711502/how-to-search-specific-lines-in-a-file-and-write-them-to-another-file-using-fun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the lines, you need to actually call the read() or readlines() methods.  In your case use readlines() which returns a list of each line in the file.  Then you can loop through that.

For instance:

```
lines = searchfile.readlines()
strings = ("neuro", "brain", "whatever")
for line in lines:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        print(line)
```

Then you can pass a list of the lines to write to another file.

Comment: Actually ```searchfile``` (as any text file like object) by default exposes the iterable interface, making not necesary to do the readline bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new file with the write flag enabled:

```
strings = ("neuro", "brain", "whatever")

with open('xxxxxxx.txt', 'r') as searchfile, open('target_file.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in searchfile:
        if any(s in line.lower() for s in strings):
            output.write(line)
```